# Enlarge Image when hover but don't make the container enlarged

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying find a way not enlarge the table when image hover happened.
here is my code . thanks

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //opacity: 0.5, 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thServer img").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: 70, height: 70 }, 100);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: 50, height: 50 }, 100);
        });
    });

</script>

<table style="border-style: solid">
    <tr>
        <th id="thServer">
            <img src="NewVersion.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this [css snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/An8RU/1/):

```
#thServer {
  width: 50px;   
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;    
}

#thServer img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it Is easy to achieve this

```
table {
height: 50px;
**table-layout: fixed;**
width: 250px;}  th {
**overflow: hidden;**
white-space: nowrap;}
```

then make the image position: absolute through jquery

```
<th id="thServer">
        <img src="NewVersion.png" **style="position:absolute;"** width="50" height="50"></img>
    </th>
```

then add more style with left and top values to position the image in the correct position.